# How can I submit only two form elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, internet-explorer-6

I seem to be stuck on a small problem, I am trying to create a "Quick Search" box for an ASP system, but I don't have code-behind access.

How can I submit only the text box value and the submit button value without submitting the ASP or other form elements on the page?

I have tried:

```
$('#aspnetForm').submit(function() {
    var $inputs = $('#aspnetForm :input');
    $inputs.each(function() {
        if ($("this:not(#QuickSearchBox, #quicksearch-submit)"))
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

And:

```
var $inputs = $('#aspnetForm :input');
$inputs.each(function() {
    if ($(this).not($("#QuickSearchBox, #quicksearch-submit")))
    $(this).remove();
});
```

But neither of them seem to work.

I am trying to have everything backwards compatible to IE 6 so HTML5 form actions are not an option, and I can't use nested forms because they don't validate and do cause some problems.

Is there any way for me to do this?

Comment: Because I need the ASP form on other pages and nested forms are "illegal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable all the elements that you don't want submitted.

```
$('#aspnetForm :input:not(#QuickSearchBox, #quicksearch-submit)')
    .prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thank you, a fast and simple solution.
But, I am already modifying the forms "action" is there a simpler way to fix all of this? (that hopefully doesn't use js or jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just wrap the two inputs that you want to submit in their own form tag?

Comment: ok wasn't sure if you had access to/could wrap the quick search in a form tag and then wrap the rest in a different form tag since you can have multiple forms on one page.